# Integration of custom page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

need to integrate the custom `php page` and its `code` into the home.php of `wordpress`. How much possibilities to include it in `wordpress` ? Any custom code for integration ? Currently the full `code` with `images` and `js` exists in theme of `wordpress`.

Comment: do you try include via `include` ?

Comment: `<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/applyonlinetab/index.php'); ?>` I tried this one..

Comment: have you tried http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom page template: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates
Once you've created the template you can just tell the home page to use it within the Wordpress page manager.

Depending on how your Wordpress site is setup you might be able to just include your custom functionality in the `index.php` file.

If the custom code your referring to adding contains functions you may want to consider making it a plugin file. Enabling it on your Wordpress blog and then calling it from wherever you need. This would keep a nice tidy separation between logic and presentation.